# Why does copy and paste often fails with firefox on xfce?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, xorg, copy-paste, xfce

I noticed that the classic X way of doing copy and paste with the mouse quite often do not work in firefox.

In all other applications it still works as it should, I mark text, and paste it with the middle button, no issues.

But for some reason it quite often fail with firefox, and it is quite annoying.
Any idea on what could be going on? and how to focus in on the issue?

When the error occurs the alternative copy and paste still works, where I mark text and use the edit menu alternatives copy and paste.

---

I'm using xUbuntu 14.04

Comment: Is Xfce just information about your setup or do you find that the problem occurs with Xfce but not another desktop environment?  When you say it "often" doesn't work, does it sometimes work?  And if it is sometimes, can you identify any common pattern or specific usage?

Comment: I only use xfce so it is hard to know about the other window managers. It may be related to what page I visit with firefox (but I have not found a pattern yet).